# Docker-swarm nginx reverse-proxy fail-over load balancing setup

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm

This is the nginx reverse-proxy configuration file for one of my sites in docker-swarm:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://site1_nginx;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So the service site1_nginx is running in global mode on a couple of worker nodes and the reverse proxy with this setup will automatically round robin to the site1_nginx containers on the worker nodes.

What I want is for reverse-proxy to only go to the service on one worker and if that service or worker fails, then it would switch to other worker and its service/container. So that other workers are there only as a fail-over backup.

Would adding something like this on top of the RP configuration file make sense?

```
     upstream site1_nginx {
        server worker1;
        server worker2 backup;
    }
```